# How to run First Program on Android Studio Emulator

Tags: android-studio

I have installed Android Studio but when running an application on an emulator, I face a problem, please help me with this issue . It shows the screen as below, please help me out
[Error during during performing emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPpPj.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can try:

1- clean project -> sync project with gradle file -> rebuild project

2- invalidate cache and restart IDE